# How to get json data from same aspx page for getJSON mehod?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get the `json` data from same `aspx` page for my `getJSON` method. I've tried the following code. Can anyone please solve this?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test_JSON.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test_HTML" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test HTML</title>

    <script src="Script/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Enter Name:
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnView" Text="View Label of Name" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getJsonData() {
            var objJson = {};
            objJson["name"] = $("#txtName").val();
            return objJson;
        }

        $("#btnView").click(function(event) {
            debugger;
            $.getJSON('/Test_JSON.aspx/getJsonData?', function(result) {
                debugger;
                $('<p> APPEND TEXT </p>').appendTo('#btnView');
                $('<p> PREPEND TEXT </p>').prependTo('#btnView');
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in this code?

Comment: `$.getJSON('/Test_JSON.aspx/getJsonData?', function(result) {` is not working. Execution is not going into this method.

Comment: @Pekka웃 What happened? Find anything?